Conjugate locus Riemann geometry
I'm reading Do Carmo Riemannian geometry. Given $M$ riemann manifold, it defines the conjugate locus of
$p\in M$ as the set of first conjugate points to $p$, for all the geodesics that start at $p$.
I was thinking: is it true that given a jacobi field (along a geodesic that starts at $p$), which admits at least a conjugate point to $p$, has a first conjugate point? can't happen that there's a succession of distinct conjugate point to $p$?
I've read some other related questions/papers, some says that conjugate points are in general discrete, some uses Morse index theorem, ... quite confusing. Is there a way to prove it using Do carmo theory? or is it something out of purpose for Do carmo book?
In general, my idea was this: let $\gamma: [0,a]\to M$ be geodesic with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$. Consider $J$ jacobi field along $\gamma$ with $J(0)=0$ and $D_tJ(0)=w$. I know that can be written as $J(t)=(d_{tv}exp_p)(tw)$. Locally $exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism, so for $t$ near $0$ there aren't conjugate points. Consider $A$ the set of $t\neq0$ such that $J$ vanish and let $\bar{t}$ be the $\inf{A}$, then for continuity $J$ vanishes at $\bar{t}$ and $\bar{t}$ is the first conjugate point.
I don't know if my idea is okay or if it can be trivially simplified, but if so, is it in general true that each jacobi field has discrete finite number of vanishing point (i.e conjugate points) that I read somewhere?

Your proof is correct.

Your proof is fine. Here is how you prove the general statement that zeros of (non-vanishing) Jacobi fields are isolated.
Let $J$ be a non-vanishing Jacobi field along a geodesic $\gamma$ and suppose $J(t_0) = 0$. Then $D_t J(t_0) \ne 0$, since otherwise $J \equiv 0$. Indeed, you can see that $\bar J(t) = J(t_0 - t)$ is a Jacobi field along the reversed geodesic $\bar{\gamma}$, with initial condition $\bar J(0) = J(t_0) = 0$ and $D_t\bar J(0) = - D_t J(t_0) = 0$. As a consequence of the uniqueness and existence of Jacobi fields, we have $\bar J(t) = 0$, which forces $J \equiv 0$.
Now, fix some parallel frame, say, $e_1(t), \cdots, e_n(t)$ along $\gamma$ near $t_0$, and write $J(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n J^i(t) e_i(t)$. It follows that $D_tJ(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n \dot J^i(t) e_i(t)$, as $D_t e_i = 0$. Then, for some $1 \le i_0 \le n$, we have $J^{i_0}(t_0) = 0$ but $\dot J^{i_0}(t_0) \ne 0$. Hence, $J^{i_0}$ is locally injective, and so $J^{i_0} \ne 0$ in a deleted neighborhood of $t_0$. Consequently zeros of $J$ are isolated.

What about conjugate locus(common zeros of all nontrivial Jacobi fields)? Is it discerete on manifolds?

@EricLey Conjugate locus of a point (or even a submanifold) in $M$ is not discrete in general. Although it has Hausdorff dimension less than $\dim M - 1$. In special cases, it could be discrete. Think of the round $n$-sphere with two antipodal points $N, S$; the conjugate locus of $N$  is the two point set ${N, S}$.

Is there a simple example that conjugate locus on complete manifolds not discerete? Or even an example that zero point of a single Jacobi field on manifolds is not discerete(In your answer you proved the zeros on tangent space is discerete)

@EricLey The conjugate locus of a point in a torus (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) is nontrivial, see the article The Cut Locus of a Torus of Revolution. As for your second question, I am not sure I understand: the zeros of a Jacobi field can only make sense in the tangent space.

Thanks! for second question: we can use exponential map to map these zeros to the manifold, namely, we know zeros of $J$, say ${t_j}$, is discerete as you have proved, but is ${\gamma(t_j)}$ discerete?

@EricLey Ah! Yes, ${\gamma(t_j)}$ will be discrete, which is essentially the Morse index theorem. See, for example, Theorem 3.2 in Sakai's Riemannian Geometry book.

Thank you for nice explanation!
